# gsutil error: Retrying request, attempt #1... Caught socket error, retrying: timed out

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud, gsutil

I'm trying to run this gsutil command

```
gsutil -D mb gs://my-bucket-213721738921
```

But the bucket is never created. This is the error message:

> INFO 0504 19:31:38.465756 base_api.py] Body:
>   {"name": "my-bucket-213721738921"}
>
> INFO 0504 19:32:38.527844 retry_util.py] Retrying request, attempt #1...
>
> DEBUG 0504 19:32:38.528234 http_wrapper.py] Caught socket error, retrying: timed out
>
> DEBUG 0504 19:32:38.528359 http_wrapper.py] Retrying request to url https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=[...]&alt=json&projection=full&key=[...] after exception timed out

Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: Are you possibly running behind a firewall?

Comment: You were right, Mike. My router had the option "Enable WAN Blocking" activated. I just deactivated that and the problem was gone. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My router had the option "WAN Blocking" enabled. I just deactivated that and the problem was gone. And gcloud is much faster now =)